# Getting Wrong output for the single data in mulesoft anypoint

Tags: json, xml, mule, anypoint-studio

I am using dw for mapping json data from XML .It is working fine . But getting Wrong output for the single data.
 XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <orders>    
        <order>
            <id>4358153417</id>
                <fulfillment>
                <tracking_number>915</tracking_number>
                <line-items>
                    <id>8367362760</id>
                </line-items>
            </fulfillment>
        </order>
    </orders>
```

Here is my dw code -

```
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
            %output application/json
            ---
            {
            orders:
            {
            order: payload.orders.order map ((order , indexOfOrder) -> {
            id: order.id,
            fulfillment: {
            tracking_number: order.fulfillment.tracking_number,
            line-items: order.fulfillment.line-items
            }
            })
            }
            }]]>
        </dw:set-payload>
```

Output with an extra null order -

```
 {orders={order=[{id=4360193928, fulfillment={tracking_number=null, line-items=null}}, {id=null, fulfillment={tracking_number=null, line-items=null}}]}}
```

But should be the following -

```
{orders={order={id=4360193928, fulfillment={tracking_number=915, line-items=[{id=8371710984},{id=8371710985}]}}}}
```

These occurs ony for single order.But ok for multiple orders.
    Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Use * before repetitive entities. Try this

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
orders:
    {
        order: payload.orders.*order map ((order , indexOfOrder) -> {
            id: order.id,
            fulfillment: {
                tracking_number: order.fulfillment.tracking_number,
                line-items: order.fulfillment.line-items
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Hope this helps..